# Bootstrap responsive CSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grid, sass

I have a four column design and I am using Bootstrap. The design renders fine in a single column in mobile devices, but in "(min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px)", I get four columns though there is room for only two. So clearly, the rows/spans setup would need to be rethought for those sizes.

The only way I can imagine of doing this is  to have semantic CSS classes used in the HTML and only including grid classes in the CSS using LESS, and then depending on screen size, including different grid classes to achieve four or two column layout. Not sure if this would work either though.

Is this the way to go with, or am I thinking this too complicatedly?

Thanks!

EDIT: This does NOT work. It only imports the rules that apply directly to .row, none of the more complicated rules .row is involved with. The reason I thought it would work is that I had seen someone do this with SASS on some other grid. Thoughts?

```
.header{
     .row;
}
```

Also at: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/twitter-bootstrap/R5jEp0oQ_-E

Comment: Twitter Bootstrap, that is. 

(The title was supposed to be "4 columns for large screens, 2 columns for smaller ones, and 1 for mobiles. Is LESS required for responsive layouts?" here too, but stackExchange had a hiccup and I forgot to fix the title after that.)

Comment: To answer the question in your comment. LESS is not needed for making responsive layouts.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you thought, but maybe you could style that portion of the page and use something like this?

```
@gridColumnWidth: 60px; // example width declared in bootstrap

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {
   .yourClass {
        max-width: @gridColumnWidth * 2
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It is similar to the suggestion at google groups, though of course usage of LESS is a plus. Still, I would prefer just playing with Bootstrap's row/column semantics and not touch the widths at all. 

As a object oriented developer, I have this ideal of proper encapsulation in my head, though I am not sure how far  that is applicable here. If Bootstrap develops, you would expect the semantics they created to work no matter what, but if you rely on their "internal" variables like gridColumnWidth, that might break in the future.